# How to check for deeply nested props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I often find myself having to build long chains before mapping over an array to check if it's defined:

```
this.props.photos &&
this.props.photos.activePhotos &&
this.props.photos.activePhotos.map(...
```

If I leave out the `this.props.photos &&` and `this.props.photos.activePhotos.length &&` my entire application will crash if `photos` or `activePhotos` is undefined.

Is there a way to check for these props without having to check every parent object/array of my end item?

Comment: `length` is redundant if `photos` can be either undefined or an array.

Comment: What is the purpose of checking `.length` of `this.props.photos.activePhotos`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### January 2020 Update

According to [the TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will be available shortly within the JavaScript standard (currently in `stage 4`).

The syntax will be the following :

```
const active = this.props?.photos?.activePhotos
```

Or the following in your case :

```
(this.props?.photos?.activePhotos || []).map(...
```

While this is being implemented, you may want to take a look at Typescript or js compilers to try out the latest ES features

---

### Old answer

An alternative could be to use a default value for your props when deconstructing them :

```
  const { photos = {} } = this.props
  const { activePhotos = [] } = photos
  activePhotos.map(/*   */)
```

In this case, if `photos` is not defined, it will be replaced with an empty object. Trying to get the `activePhotos` out of it will give you an empty array, allowing you to map on it in any case.

Comment: Why use `const` in that context?

Comment: `const` is the attribute you should give by default to your variables unless you plan on modifying them, in which case you will want to use `let`. I won't mention the terrible use of `var`. Since it does not seem like the OP modifies his props (he should not anyway) I used `const`

Answer (score 4):

I guess you refer to optional chaining, which is stage 1 of TC39

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

> EDIT: The proposal is now in stage 4 (as of January 2020) and will be added into the JavaScript standard

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing two possible approaches, according to the level of nesting.

### #1. If you have many nested props levels:

You can use [lodash.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get).

**Here's how to render `activePhotos`, only if they exists:**

```
// Please note how do we pass default `[]` as third parameter
// in order to not break the `.map` function
_.get(this.props, 'photos.activePhotos', []).map(...)
```

---

If you only want to check for deeply nested pros, then you can use [`lodash.has`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has) method:

```
// Will return `true` / `false`
_.has(this.props, 'photos.activePhotos')
```

---

### #2. If the level of nesting is no more of 2-3 levels:

Just use the native ES6 destructuring assignment + default value feature.

```
const { photos = {} } = this.props
const { activePhotos = [] } = photos

// Now you can safely map over the `activePhotos`
activePhotos.map(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check for these props without having to check every
>   parent object/array of my end item?

In general, no.

It is not clear why the `.length` of the potential is checked at the code at the question.

If the goal is to reduce the code length you can us `JSON.stringify()` and `RegExp`

```
if (/"activePhotos":\[.*\]/.test(JSON.stringify(this.props))) // do stuff
```

or if the preferred approach is using `AND` operator

```
/"activePhotos":\[.*\]/.test(JSON.stringify(this.props)) && // do stuff
```

Comment: Note, in this case "every parent object" is not checked, since `"activePhotos"` is expected to be a property of only `"photos"` property, we can omit checking `"photos"` property to meet requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**undefsafe** is a good enough library to use. There are lot of other libraries available as well.

Simple example of how to use it

```
var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1,
      d: [1,2,3],
      e: 'remy'
    }
  }
};

console.log(undefsafe(object, 'a.b.e')); // "remy"
console.log(undefsafe(object, 'a.b.not.found')); // undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a **functional approach to optional chaining** with default value return. The method uses a `Maybe` monad and a `Proxy`.

A `wrap()` function is used to wrap objects on which you can access any property safely. Internally, `wrap` creates a Proxy around your object and manages missing values using a Maybe wrapper. At the end of the chain, you unwrap the value by chaining `getOrElse(default)` with a default value which is returned when the propertie access fails:

```js
class Maybe {
  constructor(value) {
    this.__value = value;
  }
  static of(value){
    if (value instanceof Maybe) return value;
    return new Maybe(value);
  }
  getOrElse(elseVal) {
    return this.isNothing() ? elseVal : this.__value;
  }
  isNothing() {
    return this.__value === null || this.__value === undefined;
  }
  map(fn) {  
    return this.isNothing()
      ? Maybe.of(null)
      : Maybe.of(fn(this.__value));
  }
}

function wrap(obj) {
  function fix(object, property) {
    const value = object[property];
    return typeof value === 'function' ? value.bind(object) : value;
  }
  return new Proxy(Maybe.of(obj), {
    get: function(target, property) {
      if (property in target) {
          return fix(target, property);
      } else {
        return wrap(target.map(val => fix(val, property)));
      }
    }
  });
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: { c: [4, 1, 2] }, c: () => 'yes' };

console.log(wrap(obj).a.getOrElse(null)) // returns 1
console.log(wrap(obj).a.b.c.d.e.f.getOrElse(null)) // returns null
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([])) // returns [4, 1, 2]
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[0].getOrElse(null)) // returns 4
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[100].getOrElse(-1)) // out-of-bounds index: returns -1
console.log(wrap(obj).c.getOrElse(() => 'no')()) // returns 'yes'
console.log(wrap(obj).d.getOrElse(() => 'no')()) // returns 'no'
```

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@yyankowski/maybe-monad-in-javascript-to-save-us-from-the-hell-of-the-null-guard-clauses-bc9f9a1f291b) and [this link](https://curiosity-driven.org/monads-in-javascript) for more information on Maybe monads and the use of proxies.